A question on existence of graphs which might have sth. to do with finite projective plane
For positive integer $s$, consider a simple graph $G$ with $\frac{s(s-1)}{2}+s+1$ vertices. $G$ satisfies the following properties: (1) For any vertex $a\in G$, $a$ connects $s$ vertices which are denoted by $M(a)$. All the $s$ members of $M(a)$ are not connected to each other. (2) Denote the other $\frac{s(s-1)}{2}$ vertices which are not connected to $a$ by $N(a)$. There is a bijection from $N(a)$ to the collection of $\{i,j\}$ for which $i,j\in M(a)$. And the bijection maps $v$ to $\{x,y\}$ iff $v$ connects both $x$ and $y$.
What I'm interested is for which $s$, $G$ exists. Here are what I know: $s=2$, $G$ exists trivially as a square. $s=3$, it fails to exist since $s\cdot|G|$ is odd (and all the $4k+3$ odds). $s=4$, non-existence is verified. $s=5$, I do have a construction. How about general cases?
Note: I guess this looks like a finite projective plane problem, and wildly conjecture
$G$ exists for $4k+1$ primes and 2? BTW: the above shall be equivalent to this setting of $G$: (1) no triangles. (2) for every pair of vertices $i$ and $j$ which are not connected to each other, there are exactly two other vertices $k$ and $l$ which are both connected to both $i$ and $j$.
Any input is appreciated.

What do you mean by "connect"? For example, when you say "$a$ connects $s$ vertices" do you mean that $a$ is adjacent to those vertices or that there are paths from $a$ to vertices in $M(a)$?

The former. What I mean is "there is an edge between $a$ and each member of the $s$ vertices" and same for other "connect".  Sorry for the confusion.

The bipartite version of this problem (where the graph is bipartite, automatically satisfying condition (1), but we only enforce condition (2) for vertices on the same side of the bipartition) is called a biplane, and it was a subject of some disappointment to me earlier this year that only finitely many of these are known, and only finitely many are conjectured to exist. Maybe the non-bipartite case will turn out to be richer, though.

This wiki article gives 2 (necessarily equivalent) constructions for the $s=5$ case (known as the 5-regular Clebsch graph).  $${}$$ 1) $GF(16)$ with pairs of points identified if they differ by a non-zero perfect cube. $${}$$
2) Edge graph of the 4-d hypercube, with opposite edges connected.  $${}$$ Perhaps one of them generalises? Great question by the way (+1).

Maybe relevant: Ramanujan's Square Function.  Ramanujan asked in 1913 for which $x$, we have $x^2+7$ a power of 2?  Note $x$ must be odd, so $x=2s+1$.  Subbing this in to Ramanjuan's equation, we get precisely the condition that your graph has a power of 2 vertices.  Nagell and Skolem showed that there are only 5 solutions: $s=0, 1, 2, 5, 90$.  The first four of these are the four solutions you found so far: point, line, square and 4-cube with opposite vertices joined.  This may suggest a solution for $s=90$ based on the $12$-cube?

These are a special case of triangle-free strongly regular graphs.
A strongly regular graph with parameters $v,k,\lambda,\mu$, also denoted as a $\text{srg}(v,k,\lambda,\mu)$ graph, is a $v$-vertex, $k$-regular graph where every two adjacent vertices have exactly $\lambda$ common neighbors and every two non-adjacent vertices have exactly $\mu$ common neighbors. So the graphs in the question are $\text{srg}(\frac{s(s-1)}{2}+s+1, s, 0, 2)$ graphs.
In the $\lambda=0$ case, the graphs are triangle-free, and this case has drawn some special attention. The complete bipartite graphs $K_{n,n}$ are an infinite family of $\text{srg}(2n, n, 0, n)$ graphs, but this is considered boring, because they're not primitive: their complements are not connected. Apart from this infinite family, only the following are known:

Trivially, $K_1$ and $K_2$.
The $5$-cycle, which is $\text{srg}(5,2,0,1)$.
The Petersen graph, which is $\text{srg}(10,3,0,1)$.
The Clebsch graph, which is $\text{srg}(16,5,0,2)$.
The Hoffman–Singleton graph, which is $\text{srg}(50,7,0,1)$.
The Sims–Gewirtz graph, which is $\text{srg}(56,10,0,2)$.
The M22 graph, which is $\text{srg}(77,16,0,4)$.
The Higman–Sims graph, which is $\text{srg}(100, 22, 0, 6)$ and, notably, contains the rest of these as subgraphs.

It is an open problem (on the Open Problem Garden, no less) whether there are any others.
From this list, the Clebsch graph and the Gewirtz graph are answers to this question: they have $\mu=2$. (Also, $K_{2,2}$ from the infinite family has $\mu=2$: this is the $4$-cycle.)

Thanks Misha. BTW, here is a quick question: is there a name for regular graph with only the "non-neighbor" condition? i.e., only(v,k,,\mu) where a constant \lambda is not required.

I'm not sure. If you only include the neighbor condition (so you have $k$ and $\lambda$, but not $\mu$), then you get the edge-regular graphs, but I'm not aware of anyone looking at the opposite.
